# PHP - How to modify the "d" attribute of an SVG path based on a transform attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, html, svg

I have an `SVG` file with a path element inside.

This path element has some transformation (in this case an scaling transformation). Then I need to remove the `transform` attribute but getting the same visual effect by modifying the `d` attribute of the `path`. I need something like a parsing function in `PHP` to convert the `d` attribute.

For example, given this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qoswrmz6/):

```
<svg
    width="155" height="600"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="1.2"
>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="155" height="600" style="fill:#00aa00" />
<path transform="scale(0.5)" style="fill:#ffffff;" d="M 47.00,485.00 C 60.45,487.57 58.50,500.79 50.96,503.99 46.94,505.70 43.79,504.42 40.00,503.00 40.00,503.00 34.00,511.21 34.00,511.21 34.00,511.21 30.35,519.61 30.35,519.61 30.35,519.61 20.00,529.00 20.00,529.00 27.74,533.52 23.11,538.41 25.00,546.00 32.41,543.22 41.77,543.71 41.79,554.00 41.80,557.04 40.17,560.23 39.00,563.00 50.77,569.87 39.05,586.63 28.21,578.99 25.89,577.36 25.15,575.45 24.00,573.00 9.36,577.01 10.32,562.56 9.77,560.00 9.14,557.12 7.57,555.10 7.47,552.00 7.47,552.00 7.47,545.58 7.47,545.58 7.32,543.00 4.82,540.39 5.25,536.00 5.58,532.75 7.19,530.56 9.00,528.00 1.51,523.62 3.53,516.11 9.00,511.00 0.44,506.00 3.80,496.83 12.00,493.00 6.57,481.25 15.48,473.19 28.00,480.00 33.67,470.57 45.66,472.49 47.00,485.00 Z"/>
</svg>
```

I want something like:

```
<svg
    width="155" height="600"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="1.2"
>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="155" height="600" style="fill:#00aa00" />
<path style="fill:#ffffff;" d="!!!new_d_attribute_content!!!" />
</svg>
```

where the attribute: `transform` has gone but getting the same visual effect.

Comment: What would be the point of doing that?

Comment: Note that if you want to do that because you want to apply some other transform (for an animation for instance), you could embed the path in a `<g>` and apply the new transform on that `<g>`.

Comment: that's because I need to reduce space and also make the "d" attribute have values in the same ranges of my working area which will be the half: [0,78] x [0,300]. I would need to be able to make the parsing also for other shapes (rect, circle, polygon, etc.), not only the path.

Comment: yep, I know about the "<g>" with transformation but that's not exactly what I want. I need some parsing function in PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Show the actual problem then with the rect, circle and polygon. At the moment this is an XY problem.